# MySQL, find days which are not present in query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know what dates are not present in my db, i have this query

```
SELECT Hour.date
     , User.l_name
     , User.f_name 
  FROM kadry.hours AS Hour 
  LEFT
  JOIN kadry.subordinates Subordinate 
    ON Subordinate.supervisor_id LIKE "02705"
  LEFT
  JOIN kadry.users User 
    ON User.assigned = Subordinate.department_id 
 WHERE Hour.subordinate_id = User.id 
   AND Hour.date IN("2015-02-09","2015-02-10","2015-02-11"
                   ,"2015-02-12","2015-02-13","2015-02-16"
                   ,"2015-02-17","2015-02-18","2015-02-19"
                   ,"2015-02-20","2015-02-23") 
 ORDER 
    BY User.id ASC
     , Hour.date ASC
```

and in php i can process it and i can check if any date is missing, but i think there is a way to do it in `MySQL`, but i don't know how. any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is a database, and as such, it can only show you what does it have. There are some advanced select commands, but usually you should want any logic on processing data in PHP.

Remember that selecting only dates and comparing them with something in PHP usually will be much faster than complicated MySQL-sided calculations if they are even possible.

I would recommend you to:

1. Prepare a list of all possible dates in PHP (either generated or
   pre-definied). Store them in array.
2. Recover all dates from database.
3. Remove all dates in earlier prepared array that you found in MySQL. Method depends on data from MySQL, but the fastest should be to run
   foreach over MySQL records.

Comment: ok thanks, i have done processing in PHP, but thought that it can be done in mysql

Comment: @Viszman I think it's not, but I'm not sure. And even if it is, I personally strongly recommend to keep logic in PHP and limit SQL to selecting as fast as possible.